# What determines the number of hearts Wolf Link has?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, amiibo

When Amiiboing Wolf Link in, what determines the number of hearts he has? I heard it was defined by your Twilight Princess HD savefile on WiiU, but does that mean if you play on Switch you are stuck on minimum hearts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's based on Twilight Princess HD [Cave of Shadows](http://zelda.gamepedia.com/Cave_of_Shadows) save data that you save to the Amiibo itself. It does not use the normal save file from the game but the save data you save to the Amiibo after completing the Cave of Shadows so the fact that it is a different system does not play into effect.

The exact hearts you get are based on what you save to the the Amiibo once you complete a section the amount of hearts wolf link currently has still full. So easiest way to get 20/20 hearts saved is:

- Get 20 Hearts normally
- Head to the Cave of Shadows
- Get to floor 6 with Full Health
- Now save to the Ammibo

Comment: So if nothing is found, 3 hearts, if you have a cave of shadows save, 20?

Comment: @Fredy31 just added the information to the post how much hearts the Ammibo has

Comment: Some other sites say that the new amiibo comes with 20 hearts.  Some say that playing Twilight princess doesn't matter.  [GameFAQs for example](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75069283).

Comment: @TimmyJim Brand new Wolf Link's made after the game seem to be random and maybe were made with a 20 heart active save on them, the only 100% way to get 20 heart save is to do the above especially if you got Wolf Link with Twilight Princess HD

Comment: @TimmyJim There were reports that after update 1.2, wolf link "worked" as intended. If you used wolf link amiibo prior to this update, you'd always get one with 20 hearts. After this update, it properly reflects the number of hearts you had remaining in the cave of shadows (just 3 if you never started it). I know there were Reddit posts and articles about it... I'll see if I can find them and add them to my comment.